# Generating queries by string concatenation in java -- variable values are not substituted

Tags: java, database, csv, concatenation

I have the following code as part of a method which reads from CSV file and store its contents into DB by generating insert statements and executing them.

```
 ....
 try 
    {
        while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            query = baseQuery;
            st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");   
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                token = st.nextToken();
                if("TIMESTAMP".equals(values.get(tokenNumber)))
                    query += "'" + GeneralMethods.dateFormat(token) + "' , ";
                else
                    query += "'" + token + "' , ";
            }
            query = query.substring(0, query.length()-2) + ")";
            ds.insertData(query );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {            
        logger.error("IOException Occured while trying to read lines of CSV file: \n  " + e.getMessage());
        status = false;
    }
```

Everything works fine, except that the query is generated with empty values. This is printed into the logs:

```
Failed to execute query: INSERT INTO c1_ds1 ( TIME , USER ) VALUES ('' , '' )
```

I believe the problem is in these two lines:

```
if("TIMESTAMP".equals(values.get(tokenNumber)))
                    query += "'" + GeneralMethods.dateFormat(token) + "' , ";
                else
                    query += "'" + token + "' , ";
```

I have printed the (token) variable in the logs, and it's getting the values from the CSV file as it should do.
Anyone knows where is the problem?

I tried this as well:

```
query += "'"; query += token;
```

Comment: you could edit the question instead of commenting

Comment: [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is better

Answer (score 1):

Look into [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of concatenating your query via Strings. This will let the DB driver handle escaping and converting values for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly two possibilities:

- either `token` is empty; or
- `GeneralMethods.dateFormat(token)` is getting called and returns an empty string.

To find out which it is, either print out more diagnostics, or use a debugger.

P.S. It is a very [insecure practice](http://xkcd.com/327/) to build SQL queries bit by bit, since you open yourself up for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and other problems. I would strongly encourage you to rewrite your code to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: i did printing for token and it has the correct value, one of the two values is date; so it's calling GeneralMethods.dateFormat(token), while the other one does not.
For the sql injection, this is code is getting values from configuration database and its not exposed to user input at all. But i will still consider using PreparedStatement as it seems to be more efficient and might avoid similar problems.

Comment: If it's reading from a CSV file, then it _is_ exposed to user input.